# Why can't I seem to connect to my database through LocalSystem?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, service

My installer is quite simply

```
    public MyProjectInstaller()
    {
        processInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller()
        {
            Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem
        };
        Installers.Add(processInstaller);

        serviceInstaller1 = new ServiceInstaller()
        {
            StartType = ServiceStartMode.Manual,
            ServiceName =  "PageRetriever",
            DisplayName = "PageRetriever"
        };
        Installers.Add(serviceInstaller1);
    }
```

and the connection string generated by EF is

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LrcPageTaskEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.LrcPageTask.csdl|res://*/Models.LrcPageTask.ssdl|res://*/Models.LrcPageTask.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DESKTOP-300NQR3\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=LrcPageTask;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I'm not sure if I have all the users added in SQL Server ***Express***

[image]

Anyhow, when I simply try to connect to the database like in

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry(ServiceName + " started");
        PageLoadTimer.Enabled = true;
        try
        {
            repo.Add(new PageDocument()
            {
                Html = "<p>Test</p>",
                PageType = 0,
                DateAdded = DateTime.Now,
                DateProcessed = null
            });
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry(string.Format("Problem added a page document: {0}", e.Message));
        }
    }
```

but when I start my service it doesn't work an no exception gets logged!

- Any ideas what the problem is?
- If not, what can I do to identify the problem?

I've spent 20+ hours trying to fix this and I'm about to start using a text file instead of a database if I can't figure it out in the next 10 hours.

Answer (score 0):

A service running under LocalSystem can only use the machine account to connect to the database. Thus, you should grant the machine account enough permissions, or you use impersonation.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about how I "grant the machine account enough permissions"?